# How do I label features in an array by their size?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 2D boolean numpy array, `mask`:

```
array([[False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False]])
```

`mask` was generated by:

```
np.random.seed(43210)
mask = (np.random.rand(4,8)>0.7)
```

I visualize `mask` via:

```
plt.pcolormesh(mask)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Result:

[image]

I use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) to *label* the *features*, ie sections of neighbouring `True` elements in the array.

```
label, num_features = scipy.ndimage.label(mask)
```

`label` is then:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4],
       [5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

visualization:

[image]

However, I would like to have an array where the features are marked by an number showing the size of the feature. I achieve this by:

```
newlabel = np.zeros(label.shape)
for i in range(1,num_features+1): # works but very slow
    newlabel[label==i]=sum((label==i).flatten())
```

`newlabel` is then:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [4., 4., 4., 0., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 3., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 0., 0.]])
```

visualization:

[image]

**This result above (the `newlabel` array) is correct, this is what I want.** The features with only 1 pixel are marked by `1.` (blue squares in the visualization). Features with 3 pixels are marked by `3.` (green shapes on plot), while the feature with 4 pixels are marked by `4.` in `newlabel` (yellow shape on plot).

The problem with this approach is that the for loop takes a long time when `mask` is big. Testing with a 100 times larger mask:

```
import time

np.random.seed(43210)
mask = (np.random.rand(40,80)>0.7)

t0 = time.time()
label, num_features = scipy.ndimage.label(mask)
t1 = time.time()
newlabel = np.zeros(label.shape)
for i in range(1,num_features+1):
    newlabel[label==i]=sum((label==i).flatten())
t2 = time.time()

print(f"Initial labelling takes: {t1-t0} seconds.")
print(f"Relabelling by feature size takes: {t2-t1} seconds.")
print(f"Relabelling takes {(t2-t1)/(t1-t0)} times as much time as original labelling.")
```

Output:

```
Initial labelling takes: 0.00052642822265625 seconds.
Relabelling by feature size takes: 0.3239290714263916 seconds.
Relabelling takes 615.333786231884 times as much time as original labelling.
```

This makes my solution unviable on real world examples.

**How can I label the features by their size faster?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
n, idx, cnt = np.unique(label, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

n2, idx2 = np.unique(cnt, return_inverse=True)

out = np.where(mask, n2[idx2][idx].reshape(mask.shape), 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: @zabop Oops, I thought you wanted a factor, if you want to use the number of pixels you need an extra step, see update ;)